# Can't get Carousel to be visible under navbar in Bootstrap (v3.3.4) on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap version 3.3.4 (getbootstrap.com) as the CSS/HTML framework for my Wordpress site.
I have a full-width carousel at the top of my site. I have then added a nav bar which I have offset from the top of the screen by about 40px so that the nav bar runs over the carousel with the slides rolling underneath it (ie: the slides are visible at the top of the screen).

It's working correctly in Firefox, Safari (desktop & iPhone) and Chrome (desktop & iPhone), but I can't get it to work in IE8-10. I think I must have to change the position or float CSS attributes of some of the carousel elements, but just can't get it to work.

Here's a comparison image. The top of the left side is good, the top right is the IE broken version: multicomsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/MultiFixIE.jpg

Here's my site: multicomsolutions.com

**Question: Can anyone tell me how to fix my code so this feature works in Internet Explorer?**

Thank you, I appreciate any help/advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this CSS

```
.carousel-inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That worked, and without stuffing up the other browsers... Sincerely appreciate the help!